# Annotating Django querysets with counts using multiple fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-aggregation

Here is a simplified version of my model:

```
class Flight(models.Model):
    airline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=4)
```

What I would like to do is group the `Flight` objects by their common values for certain fields and annotate the groups with the corresponding flight count, as described in the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by).

I know how to do this when only considering one field. For example, with

```
Flight.objects.values('airline').annotate(Count('id')).order_by('-id__count')
```

I get something like this:

```
[{'airline': 'First Airlines', 'id__count': 21}, 
 {'airline': 'Air Second', 'id__count': 6},
 {'airline': 'Third Airways', 'id__count': 3}, ...]
```

This means there are 21 `Flight` objects whose `airline` field is `'First Airlines'`, and so on.

But how do I generalize to count multiple fields and combine into one annotated queryset that treats values from the different fields as if they were the same field?

For example, suppose I have 3 flights from Los Angeles to New York and 2 return flights the other way (there are 3 `Flight` objects with origin `'LAX'` and destination `'JFK'`, and 2 `Flight` objects with origin `'JFK'` and destination `'LAX'`). How can I get this:

```
[{'airport': 'LAX', 'id__count': 5}, 
 {'airport': 'JFK', 'id__count': 5}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can't do it in a single query. You need to first annotate on origin, then on destination, then sum up:

```
data1 = Flight.objects.values('origin').annotate(Count('id'))
data2 = Flight.objects.values('destination').annotate(Count('id'))
data = {}
for airport in { x for x in data1.keys() + data2.keys() }:
    data[airport] = data1.get(airport, 0) + data2.get(airport, 0)
```